# C++ char* to int error

Tags: c++, char, int

I would like to take a command line argument (which will be an integer greater than zero) and use it as an integer parameter in a function (to decide which part of the function to use).

```
double func(double x, double y, double z, int n) {
  if (n==1) { return 1; } 
  if (n==2) { return 2; }
  // etc
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int n = argv[1];
  // etc, later I call func(x,y,z,n) with this definition of n
}
```

When I try to compile, I get some warnings:

```
warning: invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘int’
warning: initializing argument 4 of ‘double func(double, double, double, int)’
```

I think I understand why it's happening, I just don't know how to fix it. Nothing I've found so far googling has been too helpful. I'm quite new at C++, and any information that'd point me in the right direction would be great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: `argv` is of type `char**`. You can think of it as an array of strings.

Comment: You may be looking for this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: The argument will **not** be an integer greater than zero. It will be a C-style string that, hopefully, **represents** the value of an integer great than zero. You need to **convert** that C-style string to the value that it represents.

Answer (score 1):

`argv[1]` is of type `char*`. Convert it to integer using [strtol](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html):

```
char *ptr;
int n = strtol(argv[1], ptr, 10);
/* Error checking */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::istringstream` to convert the number:

```
int main(int ac, char * av[]) {
    int av1;
    if (2 <= ac
        && std::istringstream(av[1]) >> av1) {
        do_something_with(av1);
    }
    else {
        report_error();
    }
}
```